# Como salvar arquivo em PDF de uma página embutida?

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

Eu preciso de fazer o download ou salvar o arquivo PDF de uma página embutida.

Porém, ao acessar a página de download o seletor "#download" não é encontrado, devido estar embutido. Este seletor é o botão para download.

Segue o código que estou usando

```js
const puppeteer = require ('puppeteer'); //biblioteca puppeteer

async function getdados ()  { 
    
    const inscricao = '015440380448440' //número da inscrição consultada

    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false }); //abre o browser
    const page = await browser.newPage(); //abre nova aba
    
    await page.goto('https://emissao.cuiaba.mt.gov.br/portal/'); //acessa a primeira página
    await page.waitForSelector('body');    //aguarda carregar.              
    await page.waitForSelector('#form1');   //aguarda carregar.                 
    await page.goto('https://emissao.cuiaba.mt.gov.br/portal/EmissaoGuia.aspx');  //acessa a segunda página
    await page.type('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txt_inscricao', inscricao, {delay: 100}); //clica na barra e digita a inscrição
    await page.click('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_BtnContinuar'); //clica no botão continuar                     
    
    page.on('dialog', async dialog => {
        await dialog.accept();
    }); //aceita caixa de alerta se houver
    
    await page.waitForSelector('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ASPxGrdVwPadrao_cell0_0_chk'); //aguarda carregar a 1º caixa de guia.
    await page.click('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ASPxGrdVwPadrao_cell0_0_chk')//clica na 1º caixa de guia.
    await page.click('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_BtnContinuar')//clica em gerar guia
    

    await page.waitForSelector('body > embed'); //aguarda carregar a página da guia.
    
    const url = page.url() //captiura a url atual
    console.log(url) // verifica se a url refere-se a url da guia.

    await page.click('body > embed'); //clica no corpo da página

    const download = await page.evaluate(() => {
        const uiElement = document.querySelector('#download');
        return uiElement
      }); //Procura o selector "#download"


    await page.click(download); //clicka no botão de download.

};

getdados ()
```

Comment: Para fazer a ação de salvar o PDF seria necessário um biblioteca para maniputação de PDF? Digo isso porque ao tentar utilizar o comando Ctrl+S não funcionou. Este comando faria abrir a pasta para salvar o arquivo.

Answer (score -2):

eu ja tive um problema parecido. No chrome, quando vamos abrir um pdf o robo nao consegue clicar nos indicadores dos pdf (download, imprimir etc...). Mas, ao rodar o robo com o 'headless=true' o puppeteer baixa o pdf quando clica no botão que abre ele no navegador.